# Re-routing to index after submit React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Using Redux form and React I'm making a post request to an express API that updates user information in the database. This works perfectly, however, it fails to redirect me to the index page after pressing the submit button. Elsewhere in my application `this.context.router.push('/')` has worked but not here.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { updateUser } from '../actions/index';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class UsersUpdate extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  };


  onSubmit(props) {
    this.props.updateUser(props, this.props.params.id)
    .then(() => {
      this.context.router.push('/');
    });
  }


  render() {
    const { fields: { name, email, day }, handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return(
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
        <h3>Update User</h3>
        <div className={`form-group`}>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" {...name}/ >
        </div>

        <div className={`form-group`}>
          <label>email</label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" {...email}/ >
        </div>

        <div className={`form-group`}>
          <label>day</label>
          <input type="text" className="form-control" {...day}/ >
        </div>

        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <Link to="/" className="btn btn-danger">Cancel</Link>
      </form>
    );
  }
}


export default UsersUpdate = reduxForm({
  form: 'UsersUpdateForm',
  fields: ['name', 'email', 'day']
}, null, { updateUser })(UsersUpdate);
```

Here is my updateUser function:

```
export function updateUser(props, id) {
  const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/users/${id}`, props);
  return {
    type: UPDATE_USER,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

I know it's probably a stupid error but I have spent too long looking over it! Any help would be very much appreciated.

this is a function in my application that works with `this.context.router.push('/')`.

```
export function createUser(props) {
  const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/users/newUser`, props);
  return {
    type: CREATE_USER,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`updateUser` does not return a promise from your API call hence you never enter your `.then()` statement. I think for that to work `updateUser` has to return request and just simply dispatch or something like that. In any case, you have to return your API call promise.

```
export function updateUser(props, id) {
  const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/users/${id}`, props);
  return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch ({
        type: UPDATE_USER,
        payload: request
      };
      return request;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I forgot to mention that I'm using redux-promise as middleware. My understanding of that is that it returns the promise for me. Is that correct? I have other similar functions that work, I will edit my original post to show my working function.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and it was largely as Jeremy said but the issue was with my express API. I had failed to put a `res.send` in my `post`. Thanks for the help.